# Iterator does not access full vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vi;

    vi.reserve(10);
   // back_insert_iterator<vector<int> > iter(vi);

    vector<int>::iterator iter = vi.begin();

    *iter = 1;
    ++iter;
    *iter = 2;
    ++iter;
    *iter = 3;

    back_insert_iterator<std::__1::vector<int> > iterb(vi);
    back_inserter(vi) = 4;
    back_inserter(vi) = 5;

    vi.reserve(vi.size() * 2);
    copy(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.end());

    ostream_iterator<int> os(cout, " ");
    copy(vi.begin(), vi.end(), os);
}
```

Question 1, why does `cout` print `4 5`, when I expected it will print `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5`?
Question 2,  when I replace it with `copy(vi.begin(), vi.end(), back_insert(vi))`, it will print `4 5 4 5`, why?

Comment: What does the "__1" do?

Comment: i don't know too, this is The compiler automatically adds， the ide i used is xcode 4.6.2;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, because you assign to iterators which are at or beyond the end.  The reserve() function does not update the size, only the capacity.  You might try resize() instead.

Answer (score 3):

`copy(vi.begin(),vi.end(),vi.end())` doesn't work because `std::copy` writes to the destination iterator, and you can't write to the end iterator.

`copy(vi.begin(),vi.end(),back_insert(vi))` doesn't work because the `back_insert_iterator` is changing the vector as it inserts, which invalidates the source iterators.

You might try this instead:

```
 size_t vi_size = vi.size();
 vi.resize(vi_size*2);
 copy(vi.begin(),vi.begin()+vi_size,vi.begin()+vi_size);
```